# RaspberryPi- Bash entry explanation

Tags: bash

What does this entry mean:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of `ls -l /bin/bash`:

first field: `-rwxr-x-r-x:` is the access rights:
owner: read-write-execute
group/others: only read-execute

`1` is the number of references to this inode (see hard links)

`root root` is the user and group owner of this field

`920788` is the size

`Mar 28 2013` is the modification date of this file

`bash` the filename.